# Africans Talking SDK php Laravel getDigits($options) ERROR:::: "message": "Array to string conversion",

Tags: php, xml, laravel

Am trying to build a call center with Africans Talking SDK php Laravel but am getting but an gettings an errot when it comes to getdigits($options)
ERROR:::: "message": "Array to string conversion",

```
        $welcome = 'https://call_center2/welcome_note.mp3';
        $categoryselect = 'https:/call_center2/helpcategoryselect.mp3';
        $noresponse = 'https://call_center2/noresponse.mp3';
        $callbackurl = 'https:/api/call_center/helpcategory/'.$user->id;


        $options = [
            'numDigits' => 2,
            'timeout' => 45,
            'finishOnKey' => '#',
            'callbackUrl' => $callbackurl,
        ];

  
        $voiceActions = $this->voice->messageBuilder();
        $xmlresponse = $voiceActions->play($welcome)->play($categoryselect)->getDigits($options)->play($noresponse)->build();
        return $xmlresponse;
```

Comment: Could you please share your getDigits function?

Comment: I have solved the issue already. If there is anyone using Africas Talking PHP SDK can caontact me

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add a text parameter with a value null

```
         $options = [
            'text' => '',
            'url'  => playurl,
            'numDigits' => 1,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'callBackUrl' => youcallBackUrl,
            'finishOnKey' => '#',
        ];
```